# What kind of statistic is the 'normal range' for medical lab results?

Tags: descriptive-statistics

If you've gotten a blood test recently there will be a range of values. If your results are within this range, that's considered normal. I've read that the range is calculated by dropping the top and bottom 2.5% of values. Is this a "real" statistic? Why should this range be considered normal? It doesn't make sense to me. This is how your doctor is making decisions! I would think a mean and standard deviation would be more useful.

Comment: You shouldn't consider this as dropping any values. Rather, the information is that 2.5% is above one value, 2.5% is below another value and the other 95% in between. The two are both particular percentiles. Using 2.5% is arbitrary but in many contexts (e.g. high and low weights, high and low blood pressures) being in those tail fractions might be tied up with specific advice on treatment or lifestyle. (A percentile rank might be a better system.)

Comment: In contrast mean and especially SD are likely to be harder to relate to, unless people have studied and remembered statistics and even then you need more information to interpret your value relative to mean and SD.

Comment: Note that these cutoffs aren't completely arbitrary...they are based on some medical science. If people above/below some other thresholds were known to have particular issues, then those would be the thresholds instead. If anything, those are probably fairly safe thresholds in the absence of other symptoms. If your doctor has told you your results are normal, you shouldn't worry about them unless you have other symptoms or reason to doubt.

Answer (score 1):

There is a quote I cannot seem to find now from Le Cam:

The term normal is an aberration as anyone in the medical field can attest. For patients who have normal lab values can be quite abnormal, and abnormal patients can have quite normal lab values.

Upper limits of normal are not determined by any statistical technique. Or if they are, it is important to your and my health that they be quickly defenestrated. In the time-tested tradition of evidence-based medicine, normal ranges are determined by taking several panels and reviewing trends and outcomes in the patient. Baseline values that stabilize and need no medical intervention to prevent untoward outcomes define the basis of normal ranges. Otherwise, these values are classified as abnormal. If the distinction between these values is clear (as it often is), then the lab value is determined to be a good marker and becomes a routine part of care.